IntelliJ claims package directive does not match the file location
After importing a fresh copy of an existing (working) project from the version control system, I get this strange error in some of my Kotlin files:
(The project is a Maven Java project, with one of the modules containing several Kotlin classes that up until now has coexisted and communicated with the Java classes and modules/packages without issue.)
Package directive does not match the file location

Change file's package to 'src.main.java.e2e.utils"

This is a bit strange, isn't it? Looks like the package isn't recognised/registered in some way? No packages I've ever seen has included the "src.main.java" in their name?
One of the files with the error, and corresponding "Kotlin: Unresolved reference" because of this:
I know that screenshots are often frowned upon, but I don't know any better way to show this. That the package name IS indeed correct, but IntelliJ claims that it isn't, and that the reported reference DOES indeed exist, even though IntelliJ claims it doesn't.
Please advice on how to better demonstrated this for clarity, if this isn't good enough.


I know that screenshots are often frowned upon Sceenshots of code are frowned upon. Screenshots of a GUI are fine (and specifically, the screenshot you added seems very reasonable to me). If Stack Overflow didn't want to allow screenshots ever, they would just remove the feature. :-)

The screenshot shows that felles in e2e is - incorrectly - the sources root, which means that as far as IntelliJ know, the package name should indeed be src.main.java.e2e.utils. You'll need to reimport your project as a Maven project, so IntelliJ uses the right structure (where the java folder in e2e/felles/src/main is the sources root). Maybe you imported it incorrectly (e.g. not as a Maven project), or manually marked the wrong folders as sources roots, or something else.

@yshavit, actually it would have probably been a lot easier to see the problem had the OP simply pasted the output of tree src. No images necessary

@g00se No, in this case the screenshot clearly shows that IntelliJ considers the wrong folder the sources root, and that is the root of the problem, there isn't an easy other way to obtain that information without having a screenshot.

OK, yes. I see what you mean. You''re right

Try this instead

Close IntelliJ
Delete the project folder
Git clone the project again (fresh directory, no IntelliJ metadata files)
In Windows Explorer right click on the pom.xml in the root folder
Open with -> IntelliJ


big note: push any local changes before deleting the project folder. Also check any local git stashes.

Deleting the .idea folder (and any *.iml files if they exist) should be sufficient. There should be no need to delete the entire project directory.

Sure, was just an easy way of guaranteeing a clean start
